# Why is my div header and div disappearing?

Tags: html, css

So, the div header is placed is supposed to be placed on top of the div theoretically. This code was copied and pasted from another page of my website, and I just changed the div names, because everything else is identical. However, for some reason, my div header nor the div are showing up on my page, does anyone have any idea why?

My CSS:

```
#3D {
    background-color: cornsilk;
    float: left;
    height: 180px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 215px;
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    z-level: 12;
    position: absolute;
}
#3DHeader {
    float: left;
    background-color: #111111;
    width: 490px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-left: 425px;
    position: absolute;
    z-level: 13;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px #888888;  
}
h4 {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 265px;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family:'Garamond'
}
p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-family:'Garamond'
}
```

Comment: No clue. Give us a link or put it up on Codepen or something. We likely can't figure this out from just the CSS.

Comment: If you don't add the HTML code, every answer would be pure speculation

Comment: Is it possible to include your html to go with your css so we can have a  look? or just send us the link to your webpage?

Comment: It might have to do with your CSS IDs starting with a number. Change that to see if that fixes anything

Answer (score 0):

Without your html it's hard to know, but my guess is it has something to do with your #3D... HTML ids cannot start with numbers. Try changing the ID to start with letters and change your css as well, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it appears that that was the problem. I wasn't aware of the fact that you couldn't use numbers in div ID's. Thank you again.